# How to play m3u8 using AVplayer at local

Tags: http, local, avplayer, m3u8

i try to save .m3u8 & .ts file on local ,then using AVplayer to play it, but player always loading fail. Have any way to play it , or i have to set small http server on device to put the file then play it?

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to setup a http server to server the file.  check [cocoahttpserver](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)

Or, you can try to convert the .ts file to .mp4, with [TS2MP4](https://github.com/Keemotion/TS2MP4)

I personally suggest using CocoaHttpServer, it's just simple.

Comment: thanks for answer. i'm using cocoahttpserver method to run this now .